# Implementing a script in Ionic Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I would like to implement dynamically added buttons to my Ionic app. I found that I can use the following code for this task.

The first part of the code I placed into the home.html file inside html body.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div class="list list-inset">
<div class="item-input" ng-repeat="input in inputs">
  <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type something" ng-model="input.value" />
    </label>
  <button class="button button-small button-balanced" ng-if="$index == inputs.length - 1" ng-click="addInput()">
        <i class="icon ion-plus"></i>
    </button>
  <button class="button button-small button-assertive" ng-if="$index != inputs.length - 1" ng-click="removeInput($index)">
        <i class="icon ion-minus"></i>
    </button>
</div>
</div>
```

The second part of the code I placed to the home.ts file. I tried to place this code in the main class.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.inputs = [{
value: null
}];

$scope.addInput = function() {
console.log("new input");
$scope.inputs.push({
  value: null
});
}

$scope.removeInput = function(index) {
$scope.inputs.splice(index, 1);
}
});
```

Unfortunately, I cannot define a variable:

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Because I am getting a "Typescript error". Unfortunately, I don't know how to solve this problem. I hoped that some of you will know a solution and can help me with this problem.

Comment: Can you post the detailed error you're getting? Is it just: "Typescript error"?

Comment: have you tried this ? `declare var angular: any;
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);`

Comment: can you include your package.json dependencies in your question?

Answer (score 0):

> The second part of the code I placed to the home.ts file

This statement suggests that you have created an ionic 2+ project(currently Ionic 3.x). This does not use angularjs (v 1.x) and uses angular 5.x instead.

If you want to start an [ionic v1](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/) project,

you need to set the `type` in your start command.

```
ionic start myApp blank --type=ionic1
```

Or you need to read up on latest angular docs [here](https://angular.io/tutorial) if you need to start an [ionic v3](https://ionicframework.com/docs/) project.